# Google Chrome JavaScript debugging line by line

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, google-chrome, developer-tools

I am trying to follow the guide here:
https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/scripts-breakpoints

But it doesn't seem to work, i.e.

I have done the following:

- Open the Developer Tools by hitting the Control-Shift-I shortcut
- Open Scripts panel and select "script.js" from scripts drop-down
- Set breakpoint on line 19 by clicking the line gutter (you can use the Control-G shortcut to reveal a line in a large file)
- Move your mouse over this page
- You should stop on the breakpoint

Nothing happens when I hover over "this page", and it doesn't stop at the breakpoint when I hver over "this page"...

What is going on?

I need to good way to debug javascript/jquery code

Comment: In Chrome, you can use the command `debugger;` to stop for a breakpoint at any position of your script.

Comment: @DiViS0R It's actually called `debugger;` not `debug;`!

Comment: Thank's for that. Just ran out of 'concentration fluid' (coffee).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you hover over the second screenshot on the page, it work as expected.

If this doesn't work, please try another page, as I use the chrome debugging tools quite often and I have never had a problem with it.